# Tensorflow object detection API training error(using own datebase)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Here is my environemnt:

- python 2.7
- ubuntu 16.0.4
- cuda 8.0
- tf 1.4.0

when l run this command :

```
python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr-- 
pipline_config_path=/root/tf-djx/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --
train_dir=/root/tf-djx/djxresult1
```

l use the ab path in the command and my config file.l am sure that all the path and file exit,but l met the following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ; No such file or directory